# Dynamic pipe creation/plumbing in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, ipc, pipe

I need a little help with my plumbing.

I'm trying to create a program that begins with a single process, spawns child processes based on a user-defined number, and then flow back into another (single) child process. The data flow looks something like this:

```
 /-->-█->-\
█-->--█->--█
 \-->-█->-/
```

I've got the first part of the process creation finished. The fork works well - I run it through a loop limited to the number specified by the user. It's the piping that's throwing me off.

For simplicity, I'm focusing on the first part (from parent to multiple children). So I create the pipe before forking the process - that much is given. Then I close the write-end of the child process, close stdin, dup so the child's 0 redirects to stdin, then close the child's 0. That should take care of the plumbing on the child-side, right?

So then back in the parent process, I need to plumb for the pipes going to the children. For whatever reason, this is the harder part for me. Would someone mind walking me through it a little?

Here's what I've got for this part of the code:

```
for (i = 0; i < numberOfChildren; ++i) {

    (void) pipe(workFDs[i]);    /* Creates a pipe before the fork */

    if ((workPIDs[i] = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("Error: failure when forking workPID #: \n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (workPIDs[i] == 0) {

/* ************************* WORKER PROCESS *********************** */

        close(workFDs[i][1]);   /* Closes the write-end for worker proc */
        close(0);               /* Closes stdin */
        dup(workFDs[i][0]);     /* Redirects workFDs 0 to stdin */
        close(workFDs[i][0]);

        //Fgets to get from the pipe
        //Exec sort stuff here

        }

    } else {

/* *********************** PARENT PROCESS *********************** */

        assert(inputPID == getpid()); /* Just to be sure */

        close(workFDs[i][0]);

        //Fputs to put into the pipe

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use `dup2`? It's a bit easier to deal with.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Currently, all of your children (and the parent) share a single output pipe (assuming stdout was not closed).  If you want, just redirect the parent's output to the consumer when it is executed.  If you want the parent to be collecting the output of each child, you will need two pipes for each process.

Comment: I think we need to see a more complete example.

Comment: [offtopic] always check `pipe` returned value